How to properly use of Python Paramiko channels to read data from it
This is in relation to my previous question:
Python SSH Paramiko set_keepalive not working on Linux
I'm trying to write a code that uses Paramiko's channel to execute a command on CISCO network device and close/terminate SSH session once a specific string (indicating switch began rebooting) is encountered in stdout.
Main use of this code is to launch firmware upgrade on the network switch. At the end switch reboots without closing SSH session first so command executed via SSHClient.exec_command() hangs/is blocked until underlying TCP session times out (may take many minutes). Setting keepalive on transport does not help much since there is no functionality similar to OpenSSH's -o ServerAliveCountMax in Paramiko.
I have problems developing such code though.
The code I wrote (simplified) is:
import paramiko
from time import sleep

HOST = "host"
USERNAME = "user"
PASSWORD = "password"
COMMAND = "NX-OS command"
READSIZE = 1024
ABORT_STRING = "switch rebooting"

client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.connect(HOST, username=USERNAME, password=PASSWORD)
transport = client.get_transport()
channel = transport.open_session()
channel.exec_command(COMMAND)

stdout_output = ""
stderr_output = ""
    
while True:
    if channel.recv_ready():
        stdout_output += channel.recv(READSIZE).decode()

        if ABORT_STRING in stdout_output:
            channel.close()
            break

    if channel.recv_stderr_ready():
        stderr_output +=channel.recv_stderr(READSIZE).decode()
    
    #sleep(1)

    if channel.exit_status_ready():
        break

client.close()

I started testing it on a 'regular' 'show' switch command which takes just a second to execute and exits, never displays a message indicating that switch started rebooting.
And this code only works in say 8 out of 10 cases - then it contains entire contents of stdout output in stdout_output.
In one out of 10 cases stdout contains just a part of the output and in remaining case stderr_output is empty when loop ends.
If I add one second delay (where sleep is commented) then in 10 out of 10 cases stdout_output is empty after loop exited.
After testing/debugging, it seems that what channel.exit_status_ready() returns is completely independent of whether data returned by executed command was fully (or at all) read or not.
It may happen that recv_ready() returns False (no data arrived yet from channel.exec_command()) and few lines later channel.exit_status_ready() already returns True so loop exits with no (or part of data) read from channel.
I tried to improve this loop this way:
while True:
    some_stdout_read = False
    
    if channel.recv_ready():
        stdout_output += channel.recv(READSIZE).decode()
    some_stdout_read = True

        if ABORT_STRING in stdout_output:
            channel.close()
            break

    if channel.recv_stderr_ready():
        stderr_output +=channel.recv_stderr(READSIZE).decode()

    if some_stdout_read:
    continue
        
    #sleep(1)

    if channel.exit_status_ready():
        break

client.close()

This eliminated cases where only part of stdout is read before loop exits (once some data arrives it returns to beginning to the loop) .
But still there are cases where no data was read at all yet and loop exited at channel.exit_status_ready().
I was thinking about not allowing loop to reach channel.exit_status_ready() if no data was read from stdout at all. But then code does not work (hangs) with switch commands that return no data (just return to prompt).
How can this be improved ?

Such code eventually worked for me, based on the example provided in the link in the comments:
import paramiko

HOST = "host"
USERNAME = "user"
PASSWORD = "password"
COMMAND = "NX-OS firmware upgrade command"
READSIZE = 1024
SSH_ABORT_STRING = "switch rebooting"

client = paramiko.SSHClient()
client.connect(HOST, username=USERNAME, password=PASSWORD)
transport = client.get_transport()
transport.set_keepalive(10)
channel = transport.open_session()
channel.exec_command(COMMAND)

stdout_output = ""
stderr_output = ""
abort_detected = False
 
while True:
    channel_exited = channel.exit_status_ready()
    
    if channel.recv_ready():
        data_received = channel.recv(READSIZE).decode()
        
        while data_received:
            stdout_output += data_received

            if SSH_ABORT_STRING in stdout_output:
                abort_detected = True
                break

            data_received = channel.recv(READSIZE).decode()

    if channel.recv_stderr_ready():
        data_received = channel.recv_stderr(READSIZE).decode()
        
        while data_received:
            stderr_output += data_received
            
            data_received = channel.recv_stderr(READSIZE).decode()

    if abort_detected:
        channel.close()
        break

    if channel_exited:
        break

client.close()

This checks if command executed in the beginning but does not exit the loop immediately. Even if command executed already then both streams (stdout and stderr) will be read until there is some data to read. Exit from the loop is placed at the end. Additionally I added code required for my firmware updates in the stdout stream reading loop. If string indicating that switch started to reboot is encountered in the stdout (that should be the last messagage that switch sends prior to rebooting) then no more data is read from stdout, remaining data is read from stderr and main loop exits without waiting for SSH (switch upgrade) command to finish executing.
Once loop exits, stdout_output and stderr_output contain what switch returned.
Without checking for SSH_ABORT_STRING in the output, it may take a couple of minutes (unpredictable and platform dependent) before OS detects stale TCP session after switch had rebooted and exit from the loop, and this happens only if keepalive is set. By this time switch has usually booted up.
Unfortunately switch does not terminate SSH session on his side prior to rebooting - does not inform SSH clients about all session being terminated. The same happens in regular SSH clients.
With no keepalive set the main loop may never end if SSH session is not properly terminated by the server or if SSH_ABORT_STRING is never encountered in the output.
I wanted to be able to detect that switch started rebooting and be able to track its bootup process in the script before OS-driven timeout kicks in and terminates stale SSH session.
Unfortunately Paramiko does not have both equivalents of OppenSSH's ssh  -o ServerAliveInterval and -o ServerAliveCountMax which resolve this issue when using ssh CLI client to execute upgrade. In Paramiko I had to read stdout continously and observe for messages inidcating beginning of reboot.

Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
